# c++ design question: Can i query the base classes to find the number of derived classes satisfying a condition

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a piece of code like this

```
class Base
{
public:
Base(bool _active)
{
 active = _active;
}
void Configure();
void Set Active(bool _active);
private: 
bool active;
};
class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
Derived1(bool active):Base(active){}

};

similarly Derived 2 and Derived 3
```

Now if i call derived1Object.Configure, i need to check how many of the derived1Obj,  derived2Obj,derived3Obj is active. Should i add this in the "Base" class like a function say, GetNumberOfActive()?

And If the implementation is like this:

```
class Imp
{
public:
 void Configure()
 {
  //Code instantiating a particular Derived1/2/3 Object 
  int GetNumberOfActiveDerivedObj();
  baseRef.Configure(int numberOfActiveDerivedClasses);
 }
prive:
Derived1 dObj1(true);
Derived2 dObj2(false);
Derived3 dObj3(true);
};
```

should i calculate the numberOfActive Derived Objects in Imp Class?

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CRTP in conjunction with a static counter variable: [Wikipedia Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Object_counter)

edit: some code

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> struct counter {
    counter() { ++objects_alive; }
    virtual ~counter() { --objects_alive; }
    static int objects_alive;
};
template <typename T> int counter<T>::objects_alive( 0 );


class Base {
public:
    void Configure();
    //more stuff
};

class Derived1 : public Base, counter<Derived1> {
public:
    void Configure() {
        std::cout << "num Derived1 objects: "<< counter<Derived1>::objects_alive << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base, counter<Derived2> {
public:
    void Configure() {
        std::cout << "num Derived2 objects: " << counter<Derived2>::objects_alive << std::endl;
    }
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Derived1 d10;
    d10.Configure();
    {
        Derived1 d11;
        d11.Configure();
        Derived2 d20;
        d20.Configure();

    }
    Derived1 d12;
    d12.Configure();
    Derived2 d21;
    d21.Configure();


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++-4 -pedantic crtp1.cpp -o crtp1 && ./crtp1
num Derived1 objects: 1
num Derived1 objects: 2
num Derived2 objects: 1
num Derived1 objects: 2
num Derived2 objects: 1
```

Comment: The idea seems to fit, however I'll certainly not upvote a oneliner. Could you add a code example ?

Comment: I don't see a need for a virtual destructor for counter here, a protected destructor should be sufficient.

Comment: simple rule of thumb: if a base class is meant to be inherited from make its destructor virtual

Comment: But that rule has a background - do that for classes whose lifetime you expect to be managed through pointers to the base and i can't see that being useful with `counter`. A protected destructor prevents people from doing that by mistake.

Comment: tis a bit o' over kill, no?
A simple static int adjusted in the base constructor and destructor would do the job. 
OF Course none of this would be thread safe.

Comment: This counts the number of objects that are alive. But i want to find the number of objects that has active member varaible set as true. active is an ambiguous word. Say if Enable is a bool data member, i need find the objects that are enabled or not. THanks for the help

Comment: @baash05 a simple static int won't do because you can't differentiate the inherited objects, just the number of created bases

Comment: @vivekeviv okay then, how about a factory that keeps track of the objects it created by reference counting and provides a function that returns what ever you want to know about the created objects?

Answer (score 3):

One simple possibility:

`NumberOfActive` should be `static` in `Base`. It should get incremented every time the object gets created and active is true.

Comment: This only keep track of objects created with active=true but doesn't do anything if active is changed later. Also you can't differentiate the inherited class objects

Answer (score 0):

in  Configure() method you may access to a factory of Derived* objects and get the count of active obcects